# How to specify a custom path for my .zshrc file?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to move .zshrc to a folder where I keep this kind of files synced with Github.

But now whenever I start a zsh session it doesn't use that config file.

Assuming I changed the file to ~/.dotfiles how can I add ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc to the PATH(?!) to make zsh start with that config?

Doing source ~./dotfiles/.zshrc only works for that session. Doesn't work anymore if I close the terminal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can `symlink`:

```
ln -s /path/to/original /path/to/symlink
```

For the `zshrc` you can do something like:

```
ln -s ~/.dotiles/.zshrc ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I had tried this but I had an error in the command. Thanks. It's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I suggest --> ln -s ~/.dotiles/zshrc ~/.zshrc
that is, the zshrc inside and .dotfiles does not to be hidden

Answer (score 19):

One alternative to a symlink is to put this in `~/.zshenv`:

```
ZDOTDIR=~/.dotfiles
```

If you want `.zshenv` in `~/.dotfiles` as well, you can look into setting `ZDOTDIR` in one of the global configuration files (`/etc/zshenv` is a good choice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'll stick to @nash_ag alternative.

Comment: I would, too :) Just wanted to shine some light on the usage of `ZDOTDIR`.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can do what I do and use GNU Stow. I've got my dotfiles in a repository, one subdirectory per category, like so:

```
dotfilerepo/zsh/.zshrc
dotfilerepo/zsh/.zlogin
dotfilerepo/git/.gitconfig
dotfilerepo/vim/.vimrc
```

then I can cd into repo and do `stow zsh` and it'll create a symlink from ~/.zshrc to repo/zsh/.zshrc, another from zsh/.zlogin to ~/.zlogin. `stow vim` to create symlinks from the vim subdirectory to ~, etc.

I've got a script, install-linkfarm, that does all the stow commands so when I move onto a new machine, I clone my repo, cd to it and run install-linkfarm and am good to go.

Comment: this is interesting. I'll give it a try

Comment: It's a lot less hassle than manually running `ln -s .foo ~/.foo` would be. I also like having the dotfiles segregated into their own subdirs.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in `~/.zshrc`, even as its entire contents:

```
if [ -r ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc ]; then
    source ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `export` command mentioned below to solve your problem.

```sh
export ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.dotfiles
```

Comment: Where do you place this ? In what file ?

Answer (score 0):

**In Linux**, you can check if your zsh is loading **/etc/zsh/zshrc**, and edit it.

If that's the case, redirect this to your custom script by adding:

```
sh $HOME/.dotfiles/zshrc
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an interesting hack that doesn't require you to use sym-links.
In your .xsession, (or .*wmrc) have the following:

```
xterm -e 'zsh -c ". ~/.dotfiles/.zshrc; zsh"'.
```

instead of just:

```
xterm
```

Make sure to put the -e at the end after all of your other xterm options.